# activeModel::dirty records changes even when nothing changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel, active-model-serializers

I am using the ActiveModel::Dirty library.  I have the following code:

```
def tasks_changed?
   @changed = false
   self.tasks.each do |task|
     if task.previous_changes.any?
       @changed = true
       puts 'task changed so no update'
       puts 'this task changed' + task.inspect.to_s
       puts 'here are the changes' + task.previous_changes.to_s
     end
   end
   return @changed
end
```

I a user changes something in a form, this method changes the behavior of the controller.  The problem is that one of the fields is a datetime, and for some reason previous_changes thinks the datetime changes every  time, regardless of whether or not it was changed.

The console is even telling me there are no changes.  Here is what the puts statements above produce in the console:

```
task changed so no update
this task changed#<Task id: 19, title: "task 1", content: "task 2 content", created_at: "2014-03-11 17:33:26", updated_at: "2014-03-11 20:00:01", schedule_id: 1, amount: nil, time_frame: "2014-03-27 20:00:00", state: "incomplete", denied: 0, order_number: 0, finished_description: nil>
here are the changes{"time_frame"=>[Thu, 27 Mar 2014 16:00:00 EDT -04:00, Thu, 27 Mar 2014 16:00:00 EDT -04:00], "updated_at"=>[Tue, 11 Mar 2014 15:57:44 EDT -04:00, Tue, 11 Mar 2014 16:00:01 EDT -04:00]}
task changed so no update
this task changed#<Task id: 21, title: "task 2", content: "task 2 content", created_at: "2014-03-11 17:42:18", updated_at: "2014-03-11 20:00:01", schedule_id: 1, amount: nil, time_frame: "2014-03-29 20:00:00", state: "incomplete", denied: 0, order_number: 1, finished_description: nil>
here are the changes{"time_frame"=>[Sat, 29 Mar 2014 16:00:00 EDT -04:00, Sat, 29 Mar 2014 16:00:00 EDT -04:00], "updated_at"=>[Tue, 11 Mar 2014 15:57:44 EDT -04:00, Tue, 11 Mar 2014 16:00:01 EDT -04:00]}
task changed so no update
this task changed#<Task id: 22, title: "task 3 ", content: "change", created_at: "2014-03-11 18:43:23", updated_at: "2014-03-11 20:00:01", schedule_id: 1, amount: nil, time_frame: "2014-03-31 20:00:00", state: "incomplete", denied: 0, order_number: 2, finished_description: nil>
here are the changes{"time_frame"=>[Mon, 31 Mar 2014 16:00:00 EDT -04:00, Mon, 31 Mar 2014 16:00:00 EDT -04:00], "updated_at"=>[Tue, 11 Mar 2014 15:57:44 EDT -04:00, Tue, 11 Mar 2014 16:00:01 EDT -04:00]}
```

My basic question is why does previous_changes think that there is a change every time and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

At least the `timeframe` and the `updated_at` changed. Note the a time object holds more than just seconds and the `inspect` methods does not show milliseconds for example.

But nobody will be able to tell you why this happens without providing the code that does that.

Comment: What do you mean code that does that?  I provided all code involved with the dirty associations?

Comment: I mean all code that handles the `tasks` before. You check for changes, so there must be code that might change them. Perhaps there are callbacks on associated objects, something touches the attributes, perhaps normalizers or you override the values with almost the same values for a web form. I do not know...